# Optimal way to match cases and controls w/ multiple per strata

Tags: epidemiology, matching, case-control-study

I need to do a matched analysis. However, I cannot find good reference for the best way of matching when each stratum may contain multiple cases and controls. As an extreme example, say we want to match cases/controls by their admission date (within a week for example). Within each week, there might be 10 cases and 10 controls. Should I match them as a single stratum or separately as 10 pairs? Which way gives a higher precision?

Most of the books I read only talk about what happen if a case/control cannot be matched to form a pair and therefore has to be added to another already matched pairs to increase precision.

Comment: Would be helpful to actually know more about your data and confounders... We deal with a similar scenario in our dataset (observational pharmacoepidemiological data) and use an adapted form of Propensity Score Matching to match to exposed / unexposed.